# Question about localization

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

If $A \not= \{0 \}$ is a commutative ring and $P \subset Q$ are prime ideals of $A$ then of course $P \cap (A \setminus Q) = \varnothing$ so that $PA_Q = S^{-1}P$ is a prime ideal of $A_Q$ where $S=A \setminus Q$.

My book says that it is easily seen that $A_P$ then is the localization of $A_Q$ at $PA_Q$ but I cant see this easily, can anyone clarify this to me?

Comment: It’s just saying that the two-step localization, first at $Q$ and then at the smaller ideal $P$, can be done in a single step. I’m feeling too lazy and tired to work it out, but aren’t the fractions the same for the two rings?

Comment: One approach would be to show that $(A_Q)_{PA_Q}$ has the right universal property. Alternatively, there is a criterion for this sort of thing in Atiyah-Macdonald and Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory*. I think the latter even gives your statement as a corollary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be commutative ring with identity $1 \neq 0$ and let $S, T$ be two multiplicatively closed subset of $A.$ Le $U$ be the image of $T$ in $S^{-1}A.$ Then $(ST)^{-1}A \cong U^{-1}(S^{-1}A).$

Consider the natural ring homomorphism $A \rightarrow (ST)^{-1}A, a \mapsto \frac{a}{1}.$ Note that, for each $s \in S, \frac{s}{1}$ is a unit in $(ST)^{-1}A.$ So this will induce a ring homomorphism $\phi': S^{-1}A \rightarrow (ST)^{-1}A.$ Also $\phi'(t/s)$ is a unit in $(ST)^{-1}A, \forall t \in T.$ We conclude that there is a ring homomorphism $\phi: U^{-1}(S^{-1}A) \rightarrow (ST)^{-1}A$ defined by $\phi \left(\dfrac{(a/s)}{(t/1)} \right) = \dfrac{a}{ts}.$

Now consider the ring homomorphism $A \rightarrow U^{-1}(S^{-1}A), a \mapsto \frac{(a/1)}{(1/1)}.$ Under this map image of $st$ has an inverse, for each $s \in S, t \in T,$ namely, $\frac{(1/s)}{(t/1)}.$ So this will induce a ring homomorphism $\psi: (ST)^{-1}A \rightarrow U^{-1}(S^{-1}A)$ defined by $\psi \left(\dfrac{a}{st} \right) = \dfrac{(a/s)}{(t/1)}.$

Now check that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are inverse to each other.

In this particular case, choose $S := A \setminus Q, T := A \setminus P.$ Then $U = A_Q \setminus PA_Q.$

Comment: Have I understood it right, $U$ consists of elements of form $t/1$? If so I think $\phi$ is defined wrong?

Comment: @Sodan: No. Use the equivalence relation of the construction of $(ST)^{-1}A$ to see that all the elements of the form $\frac{t}{s}$ is there, for $t \in T, s \in S.$

Comment: How does the elements of $U$ look like? The image of $T$ under which map? do u mean to map $a \mapsto a/1$?

Comment: @Sodan: You are right. I wrote it wrongly and now I fixed it. Also I misread your first question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No problems, it was a great answer. I stumbled upon another thing, if $A \setminus Q \subset A \setminus P$ then $M_p = S^{-1}M$ where $M$ is an $A$-module is the localisation of $M_Q$. How does this work? (if you got time to answer). Does it mean that $M_P= (M_Q)_{PM_Q}$? I am confused since now its a module, can I still use the above to see this?

Comment: @Sodan: Here is a hint: $M_P = M \otimes_A A_P, A_P = A_Q \otimes_{A_Q} U^{-1}A_Q$

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily stated with complements, $S=A\setminus Q$, $T=A\setminus P$, then $S\subset T$ and they are multiplicative subsets. Then prove that given any multiplicative subsets $S,T$ s.t. $S\subset T$ then $A[T^{-1}]=A[S^{-1}][T^{-1}]$ by the universal property of the ring of fractions. Never try to define a concrete morphism and check that it is bijective by hand, this is the kind of stuff that made many proofs in old books unreadable.

Comment: there is a famous example, the isomorphism $(A/I)[x]=A[x]/I[x]$, apparently there is a proof by hand attributed to J. Dieudonne in a bourbaki book which makes no use of the universal properties (i was not able to find this, and of course bourbaki's Commutative Algebra is the best (complete) book ever written on the subject)

Comment: of course, i was exaggerating a little with that claim. Bourbaki's Commutative Algebra is a great book, the best reference on the subject. But there are lots of proofs of this type, usually in old books previous to the advent of CT , when reading this books I prefer to skip this kind of proofs.

Answer (score 0):

your question is Expressive and comments almost covers the answer. I only give the isomorphism:
$$f: A_P \to (A_Q)_{PA_Q}$$

$$f(r/t)=(r/1)/(t/1)$$
for all $r\in R$ and $t \in R- P$